# From SQL database to pandas dataframe to numpy array to ESRI Table

Tags: arcpy, sql, numpy, pandas

End goal: Join data pulled from a SQL database to three different feature classes in a ESRI geodatabase.

Efforts:

1. Using PYODBC, I've connected to the database and dumped the data into a Pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import arcpy
import numpy as np


cnctStr='Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(cnctStr)

SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
'''SELECT        FILE_NUMBER, TYPE_CODE, STATUS_CODE, REVIEWER_ID, PREVIOUS_REVIEWER, OWNERS, WATERBODY_NAME, PROJECT_CATEGORY, PRELIMINARY_CATEGORY, APPLICANTS_REQUESTED_IMPACT, CALCULATED_AREA_OF_IMPACT, IMPACT_WETLAND_TYPE_CODE, CITY_NAME, COUNTY, LAST_ACTION_DATE, DATE_LAST_INFO_LETTER_SENT, IS_MORE_INFO_LETTER_SENT, DATE_MORE_INFO_LETTER_RETURNED, DATE_RECEIVED
FROM            WETLANDS_PERMIT_V
WHERE        (STATUS_CODE IN ('REVIEW EXT', 'PENDING', 'EA_ISSUED', 'MI RECEIVE', 'MI REQUEST')) AND (DATE_RECEIVED >= '01/01/2014')''', conn)

df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['FILE_NUMBER','TYPE_CODE','STATUS_CODE','REVIEWER_ID','PREVIOUS_REVIEWER','OWNERS',
                                      'WATERBODY_NAME','PROJECT_CATEGORY','PRELIMINARY_CATEGORY','APPLICANTS_REQUESTED_IMPACT',
                                      'CALCULATED_AREA_OF_IMPACT','IMPACT_WETLAND_TYPE_CODE','CITY_NAME','COUNTY','LAST_ACTION_DATE',
                                      'DATE_LAST_INFO_LETTER_SENT','IS_MORE_INFO_LETTER_SENT','DATE_MORE_INFO_LETTER_RETURNED','DATE_RECEIVED'])
```

Which works beautifully.  But, to get the dataframe into ArcGIS, I have to get it into a numpy array format because the appropriate tool `arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable` expects a numpy array.

Using the new `pd.to_numpy()` leads to this error:

```
nparray = df.to_numpy()
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(nparray, r'C:\Temp\All_Wetland_Permits_DES_EA_Dash.gdb\Wetlands_Permit_V_Output')

**TypeError: narray.fields require**
```

**Fix attempt 1:**

Found advice here: https://community.esri.com/thread/226531-arcpydanumpyarraytotable-returns-runtimeerror-create-table
to try and use this code:

```
x = df.reset_index()
z = np.rec.fromrecords(x, names=x.columns.tolist())
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(z, out_table)
```

but that leads to this error:

```
TypeError: 'in_array' is not numpy array
```

Comment: what are the types for `x` and `z`? (e.g., `print type(x)` and `print type(z)`)

Comment: `print(type(x))` - <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
`print(type(z))` - <class 'numpy.recarray'>

Comment: does this work?
`x = df.reset_index()`  `z = np.rec.fromrecords(x, names=x.columns.tolist())`   `z = np.asarray(z)`   `arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(z, out_table)`